# React render props.children fails when run children events (children are components)

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a ReactJS package. I've created a component called `Form` which contains a normal form. When calling it on the `App.js` I add components on it which called `TextField`. So, the code on `App.js` is:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Form, TextField } from 'form2'
import './App.css'

export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          <TextField placeholder="Type your name..." />
          <TextField placeholder="Type your email..." />
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the code of the `Form` component is:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      values: {}
    }
  }

  renderChildren = () => {
    return this.props.children;
  };

  render() {
    return <form>
      { this.renderChildren() }
    </form>
  }
}

export default Form
```

And this is mt TextField component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class TextField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }

  onChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ value: target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return <input onChange={this.onChange} {...this.props}>
      {this.state.value}
    </input>
  }
}

export default TextField;
```

The problem is happening when I type something on the input, the inputs disappeared and got this error message on the console:

```
The above error occurred in the <input> component
```

and this one

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
  render() {
    return <input onChange={this.onChange} {...this.props}>
      {this.state.value}
    </input>
  }
```

To:

```
  render() {
    return <input defaultValue={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} {...this.props} />
  }
```

Or (depending on the behavior your want):

```
  render() {
    return <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} {...this.props} />
  }
```

The existing code is trying to set the child of `input` to `{this.state.value}`.